# Mac computers aren't processing mailto: links correctly when they have // in them (mailto://)

Tags: macos, wysiwyg, mailto, obout

Sorry for the question title, it's a little difficult to phrase in my opinion. Here is the full question:

The WYSIWYG HTML editor we use on our websites includes a // in the mailto: link when inserted into the text editor box (mailto://). We are a webfirm and use this editor on many, many websites. For example, all the mail links inserted appear like this:

```
<a href="mailto://email@domain.com">Text Here</a>
```

We just noticed this morning that Windows computers do not include the // in the To: field when clicked regardless of the email client it's opened with. It will include the email as normal (email@domain.com).

However, Mac computers are including the // though, so whenever someone tries to send an email using these links, it's trying to email //email@domain.com - which isn't delivering, because obviously it's an invalid format with the //s.

Does anyone have any knowledge to why this is happening? The WYSIWYG editor we are using is obout. If we have to go back and remove these // from every single website we've built, it would be a tremendous task. I'm just wondering why Macs seem to not process the link correctly, while Windows computers do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Macs are processing the link correctly. Windows is incorrectly removing data and your editor is incorrectly encoding the data.

The mailto: URL scheme is defined by [RFC 2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt). It defines it as:

```
 mailtoURL  =  "mailto:" [ to ] [ headers ]
 to         =  #mailbox
 headers    =  "?" header *( "&" header )
 header     =  hname "=" hvalue
 hname      =  *urlc
 hvalue     =  *urlc
```

> "#mailbox" is as specified in RFC 822 [RFC822]. This means that it
>      consists of zero or more comma-separated mail addresses, possibly
>      including "phrase" and "comment" components. Note that all URL
>      reserved characters in "to" must be encoded: in particular,
>      parentheses, commas, and the percent sign ("%"), which commonly occur
>      in the "mailbox" syntax.

There is no provision for removing characters such as `/`.